# Create multilingual homepage

Tags: i18n-l10n, nodes

I created the basic page, then added alias `front_page`. Next, I created a translation of this node and have the same alias. In the settings `admin/config/system/site-information` in the field `Default front page` I added `front_page`, but on the home page is displayed when you switch the language is the same article, without translation. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *Variable Translation* for that:

> - In Configuration > Regional and languages: Multilingual settings > Variables, enable 'Default front page' as a multilingual variable.
> - Go to Configuration > System > Site information > Front page.
> - Change the language via the section "Select language" at the top of the page to select the language for which you're setting the front
>     page option.
> - Set the 'Default front page' option for the current language.
> - Repeat as necessary for each available language.

Relevant link: [HowTo: Different home page (default front page) for each language](https://www.drupal.org/node/1216132)